# How to center align text in a ShowMessage with Delphi?

Tags: user-interface, delphi

How do I center align text within a `ShowMessage` box in Delphi?

I have two lines and want them both to be horizontally centered aligned. Is this even possible with the standard `ShowMessage` dialog?

Comment: Try googling `delphi showmessage centre-aligned text`.  Although it trawls in a number of hits about centering the dialog box, there are also hits about centering the text.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CreateMessageDialog` procedure:

```
procedure TmyFRM.btn_messageClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
  i: Integer;
Begin
  With CreateMessageDialog('Your message to display!!', mtInformation, [mbOk], mbOk) do
  Try
    for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
      if Controls[i] is TLabel then
        With Controls[i] as TLabel do Begin
          Font.Name := 'Fjalla One';
          Font.Size := 12;
          Alignment := taCenter;
        End;
    ShowModal;
  Finally
    Free;
  End;
End;
```

with this procedure you can control you message box, for example if you don't look for `Label`s using `ControlCount` and `Controls[i]`, you can set properties for your whole window of message, like changing "Ok" button font, changing colors and.....

[image]

Comment: FYI, CreateMessageDialog uses a TForm descendant, ShowMessage may use TaskDialogIndirect.